# Toggle button in kendo grid toolbar asp.net mvc

Tags: button, kendo-ui, toggle

Is it possible to add a toggle button to the kendo grid toolbar using the template? In the below code, I want to add a toggle button inside the text tag.

```
 .ToolBar(toolbar =>
          {
              toolbar.Template(@<text></text>)
          })
```

Comment: What do you mean by toggle button, is it part of the Kendo framework?

Comment: something like this see POSITION buttons group... http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/toolbar/integration

Comment: Yes, but you will need to add the button's behavior in JavaScript, just like the example you linked does.

Comment: yes but how to add a toggle button in the toolabar template first ? The example show it in a Toolbar on its own but not grid toolbar.